# My Docker Container isn't live reloading the TypeScript compiler with NestJS

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, compiler-construction, nestjs

I'm creating a new NestJS app, but when starting dev environment, it doesn't live reload the typescript compiler. The files changes, but the compiler doesn't work how it need to do!

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    dev:
        container_name: nestjs_api_dev
        image: nestjs-api-dev:1.0.0
        build:
            context: .
            target: development
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        command: npm run start:debug
        ports:
            - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
            - 9229:9229
        networks:
            - nesjs-network
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=development
            - SERVER_PORT=3000
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=**
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=**
            - MYSQL_USER=**
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=**
        restart: unless-stopped
    redis:
        container_name: redis
        image: redis:alpine
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        networks:
            - nesjs-network
        restart: unless-stopped
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - 3307:3306
        networks:
            - nesjs-network
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ****
        restart: unless-stopped

networks:
    nesjs-network:
        driver: bridge
```

my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18 AS development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

FROM node:18 as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

I tried to create a Dockerfile and docker-compose like that, it works normally, but doesn't work the live reload when saving.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this on windows or? Kindly let us know about the operating system used too.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
The hot reload can have issue with some environments since typescript 4.9 [see release](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#file-watching-now-uses-file-system-events)
Add this code in you tsconfig build json

```
"watchOptions": {
    // Use a dynamic polling instead of system’s native events for file changes.
    "watchFile": "dynamicPriorityPolling",
    "watchDirectory": "dynamicPriorityPolling",
    "excludeDirectories": [
      "**/node_modules",
      "dist"
    ]
}
```

For more information, you can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75318862/nestjs-doesnt-hot-reload-work-in-inside-docker/75789242#75789242)