# NestJs doesn't hot reload work in inside Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

###### Minimum reproduction code

[sample code](https://github.com/Nundy/doesn-t-hot-reload-issue)

###### Steps to reproduce

1. npm install
2. docker compose up

###### Expected behavior

wait for the docker container to be created and run nest, modify the main.ts file, the nest listener does not perform hot reloading

###### package.json

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.2.4",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "29.3.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
```

###### Dockerfile

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .

USER node
```

###### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '2.13.0'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      # Only will build development stage from our dockerfile
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    # Run in dev Mode: npm run start:dev
    command: npm run start:dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

#### use the listening mode in the docker container, and bind the volume, but modify the file under src, nest does not perform hot reload

Comment: Docker is designed as an isolation environment and it can't normally access host files at all.  Instead of installing Docker and setting up this roundabout Compose-based solution with a Dockerfile that mostly gets ignored, can you use Node directly without Docker for this sort of development task?

Comment: @DavidMaze Indeed, as you said, locally in the docker container may encounter more difficult problems

Answer (score 9):

Since typesript 4.9 the watcher check file changes using the system’s native events for file changes : [see release](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#file-watching-now-uses-file-system-events)
I had the same problem using docker with windows (mount volume stuffs)

I do not find any parameter in nest to force the usage of the legacy mode directly. But if you're using the typescript compiler in your project ( tsc ), you can override default configuration with the configuration file. In my case it's "tsconfig.build.json"

You can update the configuration file to force typescript to watch differently as follow :

```
"watchOptions": {
    // Use a dynamic polling instead of system’s native events for file changes.
    "watchFile": "dynamicPriorityPolling",
    "watchDirectory": "dynamicPriorityPolling",
    "excludeDirectories": [
      "**/node_modules",
      "dist"
    ]
}
```

You can see other options in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#watch-watchFile). I tried the "fixedPollingInterval" but I issued an high CPU usage. For now dynamicPriorityPolling do the job.

Comment: This did the trick for me, thank you for the solution. As far as CPU usage - I see a rise of only 1 to 2% on my machine (i7-12700).